# The data filter before the http request completely

Tags: javascript, angular

I got all the menu list by http request and then pass it to vertical moudle,
and then vertical module use menu list to filter parent menu,but when vertical moudle filter,the http request does not get the data completely,how I can solve this problem? Thank you!

```
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
  public menuItems: Array<any>;
  public settings: Settings;

  constructor(public appSettings: AppSettings, public menuService: MenuService) {
    this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuItems = this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems();
  }

}

<div id="vertical-menu" [perfectScrollbar]="psConfig" [disabled]="!settings.fixedSidenavUserContent">
    <app-vertical-menu [menuItems]="menuItems" [menuParentId]="0"></app-vertical-menu>
  </div>
```

```
export class VerticalMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('menuItems') menuItems;
  @Input('menuParentId') menuParentId;
  parentMenu: Array<any>;
  public settings: Settings;

  constructor(public appSettings: AppSettings, public menuService: MenuService) {
    this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
// when filter the menuItems.length=0
    this.parentMenu = this.menuItems.filter(item => item.parentId === this.menuParentId);
  }

}

<div *ngFor="let menu of parentMenus" class="menu-item">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try set function in child:

```
  parentMenu;
  @Input()
  set menuItems(passedValue: any[]) {
    console.log(passedValue)
        if (!passedValue.length) {
            return;
        } else {
            this.parentMenu = passedValue.filter(item => item.parentId === this.menuParentId);
        }  
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahh4h7)

Comment: I did as you see,but I found when the length of passedValue is 0,the filter method execute,how to execute the filter when the data of passedValue load completely,Thank You!

Comment: What do you gei if log this.menuItems in ngOninit?